# Flutter App Name doesn't support image insertion here

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When I try to select a GIF via keyboard, it says App Name doesn't support image insertion here.. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Can you show your code and put the error that you got?

Comment: There's no error  but here's the message. https://imgur.com/cJDADe8

Comment: What is going on in your code when you trying to pick a gif ? Please share a part of that code, otherwise I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, flutter is not support commit gif/sticker/image on keyboard yet, if you need this so badly, you have to implement on your own, and gen flutter framework again, which is take a hour for that. For more information check here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20796

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [contentInsertionConfiguration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/EditableText/contentInsertionConfiguration.html) property, it is now supported.